# error: incompatible types return scores; required: int found: ArrayList<Integer>

Tags: java

```
//Class declaration of Player class
public class Player
{
/*--------------- Data Fields ---------------------------------------
Attributes of the class
*/
private String name;
private int playerId;
private int bestScore;
private static int numberOfPlayers = 0;
private ArrayList<Integer> scores = new ArrayList<Integer>();

//Create set method for setScores
public void setScore(int score)
{
    scores.add(score);
}

//Create get method for getScores
public int getScores()
{
    return scores;
}
}
```

I tried looking for a solution but I cannot seem to find one. I was ask to store 5 scores for one player for a guessing game. Im just wonder what should I put into the getScore method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look here, the problem is here:

```
public int getScores()
{
    return scores;
}
```

You're returning an ArrayList from a method which declares it returns an int

Comment: so I changed it to `//Create get method for getScores
 public ArrayList<Integer> getScores()
 {
  return(scores);
 } `hope this works now